# why the background image is not set using angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hi can you please tell me why my background image not set .?I need to set same image in all views ?And 
Can you please tell me how to show different images in different views how I can achieve this ?
plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/KfY9Xo2br3AD6UOzoZlE?p=info

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.x" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@0.10.0" data-semver="0.10.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.1.1" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-route@1.2.17" data-semver="1.2.17" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.17/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body  ng-style="{'background-image':'url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9b/Domestic_cat_cropped.jpg/250px-Domestic_cat_cropped.jpg)'}">
   <div ng-app="app">
      <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You bootstrapping the app after the ng-style which is incorrect. It should be like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.x" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@0.10.0" data-semver="0.10.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.1.1" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-route@1.2.17" data-semver="1.2.17" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.17/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body  ng-style="{'background-image':'url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9b/Domestic_cat_cropped.jpg/250px-Domestic_cat_cropped.jpg)'}">
   <div>
      <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

[Working Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/E1x9BnJdvJpE1Ub6i4LF?p=preview)

Comment: how to add different image in different screen

Comment: you need to put it in diffrent divs inside ng-view

Comment: can you just give one pluker for that

Comment: As I have two view and I need to show Different background image

Comment: do you have idea of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25266793/why-drag-and-drop-not-occur-in-jstree-using-angular

Comment: or this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25278641/how-to-add-item-in-treenode-view-using-angular

Comment: sure will look at them straight away

Answer (score 1):

You initialised the Angular application after setting ng-style!!!

Make sure to include ng-app="app" on the body tag and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `ng-app="app"` from div to html tag.